# How to plot multiple histograms for two factors

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I have a data.frame like this (simplified, in fact there are more values per parameter):

```
   params        value status
1    par1 9.214378e-01   good
...
5    par1 3.907796e+03   good
6    par1 1.440000e-01   bad
...
13   par1 5.343397e+01   bad
14   par2 3.430469e-03   good
...
18   par2 5.722368e-01   good
19   par2 3.764936e-03   bad
...
26   par2 1.291550e-01   bad
27   par3 4.750810e-01   good
```

with values for 20 parameters for two factors each 'good'/'bad'.
I would like to plot it as a set of diagrams in tabular form where I can see differences 'good' versus 'bad', two overlapping histograms for each parameter.
Each parameter lives in its characteristic interval.

I have tried with ggplot

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = DF) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=value, color=status)) +
  facet_wrap(~params)
```

but that doesn't work - the bars are stacked one on the other
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `position = 'dodge'`, otherwise the bars will be stack.

I guess you are looking for:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=value, fill=status)) +
           geom_histogram(position = 'dodge') +
           facet_wrap(~params)
```

Please make your question more specific, i.e. it's not 2 factors, but one with 2 levels.

Comment: My solutons works as well and does not produce bars stack on each other. What looks like bars being stack on each other is in fact two bars at the same position.
However, your solution produces finer histogram bars which increases the readability of the plot if you have around 1000 values as I do.

Comment: On the other hand missing `scales = "free"` makes the x axis having same min/max values on all histograms. You are of course right with the factors/levels, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, among others `scales = "free"`, was missing

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = DF) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=value, fill=as.factor(status))) +
  facet_wrap(~params,scales = "free")
```

The plots looks now, for 10 parameters only,
[image]